# How to override the login page provided by abp.io?

Tags: authentication, frameworks, overriding, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I tried to override my custom login with LoginModel and Login.cshtml as described [here](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd).

After replacing Login.cshtml and myCustomeLoginModel.cs, this error is shown :

> 'LoginModel' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

and this is the code of myCustomLoginModel.cs after replacing :

```
 public class myCustomLoginModel: LoginModel
    {
        public myCustomLoginModel(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
                                  IOptions<Volo.Abp.Account.Web.AbpAccountOptions> accountOptions)
        : base(schemeProvider, accountOptions)
        {
        }
    }
```

and then all properties of myCustomLoginModel is not recognized in Login.cshtml like this :
[The properties of myCustomLoginModel is not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6By8.png)

What did I miss ?

I tried to send any text for [@hikalkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1044430/hikalkan), the contributor of this concept at [abp.io](https://abp.io), but I did not found any email or contact info that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had a fault!
I had created a class named 'LoginModel.cs' under the Login.cshtml.
I don't know how this happened.
But this causes errors.

If I followed exactly what was in the document, it would work nicely!